# document is not defined in nuxtjs on integrating jqxwidget

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, jqwidget

I'm integrating jqxWidgets(https://www.jqwidgets.com/vue/) into my nuxtjs app.
Here are the steps I did:
installed jqwidgest `npm install --save jqwidgets-scripts`
After I imported the jqxGrid on my page `import JqxGrid from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-vue/vue_jqxgrid.vue";` I received an error for document is not defined.

I created a plugin jqwidgets.js and added the following code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import jqGridWidget from "jqwidgets-scripts";

Vue.use(jqGridWidget)
```

in nuxtconfig.js I added the following in plugins: 
`plugins: [{src: "~/plugins/jqwidgets.js", ssr: false}]`

and in build I added:

```js
build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
    },
    transpile: [/^jqwidgets-scripts($|\/)/],
  }
```

I am still getting the document is not defined error in `node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Any updates on this ?